# Generating an array of school grades

Tags: php

I have a catalogue of activities that are marked based on the age group that they are relevant to. There are 14 checkboxes for checking what grades. K, 1 - 12, and Adult. I have a switch statement to change the K and Adult to a numeric representation.

The following PHP code grabs the grades checked and displays them in consecutive groups.
Aka. K, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11, Adult will display as K - 3, 5 - 7, 10 - Adult.

What I would like to ask is, is this a clumsy solution for my problem? Can I learn to make this more efficient or less prone to issues?

```
// generated through database, but set manually here for testing
$new_grades_array = array(K, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11, Adult)

// grades related variables 
$last = ""; // records previous grade in loop for checking consecutiveness
$display = ""; // concatenated display of results
$conseq = FALSE; // records if previous grade was consecutive

for ($i = 0; $i < count($new_grades_array); $i++):

     // set grade digit for K and Adult
     switch ($new_grades_array[$i]):
           case "K":
               $currentgrade_dig = 0;
               break;
           case "Adult":
               $currentgrade_dig = 13;
               break;
           default:
               $currentgrade_dig = $new_grades_array[$i];
     endswitch;

     // concatenates string to display variable based on situation
     if ($i == 0): // if the first grade listed

          $display = $new_grades_array[$i];

     elseif ($i +1 == count($new_grades_array)): //if the last grade listed

          if ($conseq != FALSE): 
               $display .= " - " . $last . ", " . $new_grades_array[$i]; 
          else: 
               $display .= ", " . $new_grades_array[$i];
          endif;

         $conseq = FALSE;

     elseif ($currentgrade_dig - $last ==1): // if consecutive number from previous
          $conseq = TRUE;

     else: // if not a consecutive number

          if ($conseq != FALSE): 
               $display .= " - " . $last . ", " . $new_grades_array[$i];
               $conseq = FALSE;
          else:
               $display .= ", " . $new_grades_array[$i];
          endif;
     endif;

     $last = $new_grades_array[$i];

endfor;

print $display;
```

Comment: You could replace the switch statement with an lookup array. And instead of the for-loop, you can use an foreach-loop

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you're not using { and }?

Comment: The BEST reason, I think, is because it is in a template and I believe it is somewhat standard in templating? I was working inside of a template someone else had created and they were using the alternative syntax. I actually prefer the alternative syntax because I think it makes my code easier for me to read. Since then, I've read that it is an old syntax that it is being used less. So I am not sure if I will continue when coding in general.

Comment: Using alternate syntax in php code (where you're not jumping in and out of php/html) makes it _harder_ to read because blocks are not immediately identifiable.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some tips.

### 1) Have a function that returns the grade value.

This helps avoid duplicated code and increases readablilty.

Code:

```
function getGradeValue($val){
  switch ($val) {
  case "K":
    $val = 0;
    break;
  case "Adult":
    $val = 13;
    break;
  default:
  }
  return $val;
}
```

### 2) Create a function to retrieve the final output.

This allow for an easier way to test the overall functionality and helps to eliminate global variables.

### 3) Create unit tests to speed up testing

Simple Testcases:

```
function println( $str ){
  print( $str . "<br/>\n" );
}
function testThis( $arr, $expect ){
  $result = getGroupedGradesAsString( $arr );
  if( $result == $expect ){
    println( "Passed:" );
  }else{
    println( "Fail:" . $result . " != " . $expect );
  }
}
testThis( array("K", 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11, "Adult"), "K - 3, 5 - 7, 10 - 11, Adult" );
testThis( array("K"),  "K" );
testThis( array("K", "Adult"),  "K, Adult" );
testThis( array("K", 1, 2, 7, 11, 12), "K - 2, 7, 11 - 12" );
testThis( array( 6, 7, 8), "6 - 8" );
testThis( array("K", 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12), "K, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12" );
testThis( array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, "Adult"),  "1 - Adult" );
```

### 4) Use a loop to find the last consistent number.

Refer to `getGroupedGradesAsString()` in the final code for more information.

### Final Code:

```
<?php
// By Larry Battle [http://bateru.com/news/]
function getGradeValue($val){
  switch ($val) {
  case "K":
    $val = 0;
    break;
  case "Adult":
    $val = 13;
    break;
  default:
  }
  return $val;
}
function getGroupedGradesAsString($arr) {
  $output = "";
  for ($i = 0, $len = count($arr); $i < $len; $i++) {
    $output .= (($i) ? ", " : "" ) . $arr[$i];
    if( getGradeValue($arr[$i]) == getGradeValue($arr[$i+1])-1 ){
      do{
        $i++;
      }while( getGradeValue($arr[$i]) == getGradeValue($arr[$i+1])-1);
      $output .= " - " . $arr[$i];
    }
  }
  return $output;
}
?>
```

Demo here: http://codepad.org/zi8oavlv

Here's a shorter version but might be a litter bit harder to understand.

```
<?php
    // By Larry Battle [http://bateru.com/news/]
function getGradeValue($val){
    return ( $val == "K" || $val == "Adult" ) ? (($val == "K") ? 0 : 13 ) : $val;
}
function getGroupedGradesAsString($arr) {
  $output = "";
  for ($i = 0, $len = count($arr); $i < $len; $i++) {
    $output .= (($i) ? ", " : "" ) . $arr[$i];
    if( getGradeValue($arr[$i]) !== getGradeValue($arr[$i+1])-1 ){
        continue;
    }
    while( getGradeValue($arr[++$i]) === getGradeValue($arr[$i+1])-1);
    $output .= " - " . $arr[$i];
  }
  return $output;
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi Larry! Thanks for your tips, I will use these for future programming! I am impressed at how short your getGroupedGradesAsString function is and will study that to improve my coding later. Also, my output was not completely correct, but in yours it is. I didn't catch it because I was only testing it against one array situation. I have never seen a test function to compare output with desired output, so thank you for sharing that.

Answer (score 0):

If we are speaking about conversion of some numeric value to its text representation when some very limited number of numeric values has non-numeric text representation and vice versa, then the most efficient way will be:

```
$display = $i == 0? "K" : ($i == 13 ? "Adult" : $i);
$i = $text == "k" ? 0 : ($text == "Adult" ? 13 : $text);
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks like it will be very useful. I am not familiar with the above syntax though, could you explain it or give me a term to lookup?

Comment: It is a ternary operator. It exist in many modern languages. `op1 ? op2 : op3` The first operand is a boolean expression. If its value true then the op2 is evaluated otherthise op3 is evaluated

Comment: @SweetTomato it's called a "ternary operator". Search for that term [on this page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Comment: http://php.net is a very good souce of information on php. I believe the best one.

Comment: Thank you! I used the ternary operator by changing my switch statement to:        $currentgrade_dig = $new_grades_array[$i] == "K" ? 0 : $new_grades_array[$i] == "Adult" ? 13 : $new_grades_array[$i];

Comment: Reading the page recommended by @bhamby, I found that return-by-reference functions and stacking ternary operators are not recommended. Am I doing both in my example since I am looking for the K, then Adult, then referencing $new_grades_array[$i]?

Comment: 1) there is no returning by reference in my example. 2) "Obvious" to who? To the programmer or to the compiler? ;)

Comment: Yes, I did a mistake. well, no one is error proof. I fixed the answer

Comment: Thanks @serge, I didn't realize it was a problem that could be fixed with the parenthesis. So, stacking is not recommended when you don't explicitly state the order of operations? (And I think I misunderstood the returning-by-reference statement, so never mind on that)

Comment: Not at all, Thank you to make me looking at this. Actually I was surprised that php evaluates this operator in non-usual (at least for me) direction

Comment: Many people recommend using explicit parentheses for any complex expression where the default precedence isn't obvious. Stacked ternary expressions are definitely one of these cases.